# How to refer to someone who works at a hotel?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I understand that a *hotelier* is *"someone who owns or manages a hotel"* ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelier)), much like a *hotelkeeper* ([reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hotelkeeper)). However, these functions (owning and managing) are far too specific, the same way a *concierge*, a *receptionist* and a *hotel desk clerk* are.

I have also seen a few references to the word *hotelry* used as an adjective meaning "things that are related to hotels", but there doesn't seem to be any such entry in dictionaries.

Thus my questions are:

> - Is there a word in English to refer to *"people that work in hotels"?*
> - Is there a word to refer to *"things that are related to the realm of hotels"*?

Comment: Hotel workers, hotel employees. They work in a hotel, don't they?

Comment: He's a *hotel worker*. She's in the *hotel and catering trade*.

Comment: or an "hotel employee", one that belongs to "hotel staff".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general term is *hospitality worker*.  This broadly refers to someone who works in the [hospitality industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospitality_industry), which also include, for instance, restaurants.

Comment: I would not use *hospitality worker* for *hotel worker*. I don't know exactly, but it doesn't sound better than *hotel worker*.

Comment: It might sound better in a resume, don't you think?

Comment: @BellAppLab It is primarily-opinion-based.

Comment: I think there's a context where it makes sense. I wouldn't ask the front desk if a "hospitality worker" can take care of something. I would refer in corporate documentation or survey results to hospitality workers, because the term is generally accepted and well defined.

Comment: Precisely. Academia also refer to the subject as "hospitality management" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospitality_management_studies).

Comment: @Jimm101 is right.  The hotel and restaurant industry is generally referred to as the "hospitality industry."  People who work for hotels are said to work in "hospitality," so such workers are commonly called either "hospitality workers" and/or "hospitality industry workers."  These terms are the industry standard; they're boilerplate plate language.

Comment: Some (or arguably all) hotel workers are hospitality workers. Some (but certainly not all) hospitality workers are hotel workers. The latter does not at all imply the former. Might as well say that a person living in Alaska is a right-handed person.

Comment: @Drew No, not all Alaskans are right handed.

Answer (score 0):

In very broad strokes, hotels are part of the hospitality industry. In most cases this can stand alone without tagging "worker" or anything on.

> *Bob:* What line of work are you in?
>   *Alice:* I work in hospitality.

If you need something more specific I would suggest using "hotel staff". This could cover virtually any non management role and is a bit more classy than "hotel worker" or similar.